# \src@load@hook undefined error after Miktex update and using

Tags: templates, hooks

I know it is normal practice to place a MWE, however in this case, I hope by just stating the error, you can help me down some path I can take to resolve this issue.

I have been using [Harvey Sheppard's Template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends/279318#279318) for quite some time now.  However, after updating Miktex last night (October 30th 2020), I get this error:

> ! Package etoolbox Error: \scr@load@hook undefined.
>
> See the etoolbox package documentation for explanation. Type  H
>   for immediate help.  ...
>
> l.55 \renewrobustcmd*\scr@load@hook
> [2]{% ?
>
> ! Package etoolbox Error: \scr@set@load@hook undefined.
>
> See the etoolbox package documentation for explanation. Type  H
>   for immediate help.  ...
>
> l.59 \renewrobustcmd*\scr@set@load@hook
> [2]{\csgappto{#2-@#1}} ?
>
> Process has been terminated ...

Again, I know this is not normal procedure as this question is without a MWE, but I do hope that the error output can give some guidance to a suitable solution.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

This is a ME from his "yReport" class:

```
\documentclass[article, french]{yReport}

\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{\marginparsep}

\author{Harvey Sheppard}
\subtitle{Géographie}
\title{Géopolitique\\et Sécurité informatique}

\makeatletter
\let\runauthor\@author
\let\runtitle\@title
\makeatother

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\sideDate}{m}{\vspace{1mm}{\normalsize\lightBoldFont#1\\}}

\begin{document}
    \titleTwo[images/anonymous.png]
    
    \startcontents
    \printMarginPartialToc[1][En Bref]
    
    \section{Introduction}
    \enquote{Internet}...
    Aujourd'hui, avec l'avènement des smartphones, le réseau électronique s'est infiltré partout.
    Son omniprésence semble faire penser à certains qu'Internet est un droit fondamental de l'Homme.

    Elles ont probablement été vendues sur le dark-net ou utilisées directement.
    
\end{document}
```

I let the code run through and just took out a snippet from the log file that has the hook error code:

**Snippet of LOG File**

```
\itf@sk=\skip140
\itf@musk=\muskip17
\itf@tk=\toks43
\itf@cnt=\count331
\itf@calc@Askip=\skip141
\itf@calc@Bskip=\skip142
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/interfaces\interfaces-etoolbox.sty"
Package: interfaces-etoolbox 2011/02/19 v3.1 more etoolbox-like commands (FC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/interfaces\interfaces-scrlfile.sty"
Package: interfaces-scrlfile 2011/02/19 v3.1 scrlfile hooks improved (FC)


! Package etoolbox Error: \scr@load@hook undefined.

See the etoolbox package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.55 \renewrobustcmd*\scr@load@hook
                                   [2]{%
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


! Package etoolbox Error: \scr@set@load@hook undefined.

See the etoolbox package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.59 \renewrobustcmd*\scr@set@load@hook
                                       [2]{\csgappto{#2-@#1}}
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/interfaces\interfaces-pgfkeys.sty"
Package: interfaces-pgfkeys 2011/02/19 v3.1 pgfkeys handlers definitions (FC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/interfaces\interfaces-tikz.sty"
Package: interfaces-tikz 2011/02/19 v3.1 load tikz libraries easily (FC)
)
```

Comment: As a first step check for updates in admin mode *and* user mode. If the problem persists provide a MWE and the log-file as one has to check the versions of the files involved.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I tried both modes and still no success.  How do I upload the log-file?  Thanks!

Comment: well if you have a MWE the log should be short enough to copy it in the question.

Comment: Open an issue at the github of your template. The interfaces package should not be used. It patches lots of other packages but hasn't been updated since nearly 10 years. I see there is already an issue and I added a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ulrike Fischer, who opened up a ticket and notified Harvey Sheppard about the error being cast with the current packages.  Mr. Sheppard then modified his [template `sty` file](https://github.com/HarveySheppard/yLaTeX) to work with the current packages.